# Active Directory cross-domain search

Tags: active-directory, ldap, cross-domain

I have an Ative Directory forest with two domains, AA.RR.COM, and BB.RR.COM, that contain users and groups.
I need to search users in both domains, while querying against one of them, or example, AA.RT.COM
How can I tell AD to run my LDAP query against all neighbour domains in the forest?

Here is my code:

```
using (var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(new DirectoryEntry(adServerName, adLogin, adPassword)))
{
    var filter = string.Format("(&(objectClass=person)(|(givenName=*{0}*)(displayName=*{0}*)(sn=*{0}*)(mail=*{0}*)))", valueToSearch);

    searcher.ReferralChasing = ReferralChasingOption.All;

    searcher.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(new[] { 
        "samaccountName", 
        "memberOf", 
        "displayname", 
        "mail" });

    searcher.Sort = new SortOption("samaccountname", SortDirection.Ascending);
}
```

This work fine when all users are in the same domain, but not when they are distributed within several domains in the same forest.

Any help is appreciable.

Answer (score 4):

Since you said AA.RR.COM, and BB.RR.COM are in the same Active Directory forest, you can check if Global Catalog is running in your forest.  If you have Global Catalog running, you can run a LDAP query against the global catalog.  Here is the example code assuming there is a global catalog in AA.RR.COM.

```
using (DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(new DirectoryEntry("GC://AA.RR.COM")))
{
    var filter = string.Format("(&(objectClass=person)(|(givenName=*{0}*)(displayName=*{0}*)(sn=*{0}*)(mail=*{0}*)))", valueToSearch);

    searcher.ReferralChasing = ReferralChasingOption.All;

    searcher.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(new[] { "samaccountName", "memberOf", "displayname", "mail" });
    searcher.Sort = new SortOption("samaccountname", SortDirection.Ascending);
    foreach (SearchResult result in searcher.FindAll())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(result.Path);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

So, a few things:

- You need to go against a global catalog. You can see the sample binding in Harvey's note.
- You need to replace `(objectClass=person)` with `(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)`
- Your search filter is incredibly inefficient. None of the attributes you list have the type of index necessary to do a medial search in a semi-efficient manner by default. At a minimum, you should at least replace
- Based on what it looks like you're doing, you should see if an ANR search is what you really want - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223243(PROT.13).aspx
- Doing server side sorts can be expensive and could fail with a large result set. You may want to do this locally
- You should add a PageSize to your searcher